# Print python float as single precision float

Tags: python, python-3.x

When printing a floating point variable in Python 3 like this:

```
str(1318516946165810000000000.123123123)
```

The output is:

```
1.31851694616581e+24
```

Is there a simple way in the standard lib (not Numpy) to print the same thing with only 32 bit float precision? (or more general any precision)

Be aware precision != places, like in Decimal

EDIT

The result should should be a string like str does but with a limited precision for example:
32 bit representation of the above float:

```
1.31851e+24
```

Comment: You mean you want to truncate the decimal representation of a float so that it doesn't give a false impression of accuracy?

Comment: Yes, while still ensuring that the result would represent a valid 32 bit float (or any bit precision, like 24 bit), the goal is a string and not the actual python float. I hopend that there would be another way than to manually parse the string again and ensuring said restricitions

Comment: So you want a lossless function that can turn a float into a string and back? Does it have to be human readable?

Comment: I'm gonna edit the question to clarify

Comment: -Done (filler text to make comment length long enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood, but is using `format` with a suitable precision modifier what you are asking for?

```
>>> "{0:6g}".format(1.31851694616581e24)
'1.31852e+24'
```

Change the `6` to control the number of significant figures

Comment: 'g' rounds the number to x significant digits (not bits), does not guarantee a valid representation for a 32-bit float, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language for details, what could happen is that the float would have a higher or lower value with 6 digits than would be allowed for a x-bit float, none of the format string modifiers looks for bit length

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification, sorry my answer's not a lot of help to you.

Comment: But it can be used in my use case when no further validation is required and a small loss of precision can be ignored, accepting as 'near enough' because there seems no sensible one-liner in the standard lib